# Spring Cloud Config Server: configure git pull interval

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Cloud Config Server connected to Eureka Server with BitBucket git repository.
I found out under debugger that `org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand#call` is being invoked via scheduler each time Config Server is updating it's status with Eureka.
Moreover, it's invoked each time connected services are querying for the updated config, and even each time `/health` endpoint is requested on Spring Cloud Config Server or on the connected client.

I believe it's a big overhead in terms of HTTP response time, but also in terms of the outgoing traffic.

Is there a way to update locally cloned repository less often?

P.S. I know that there is a [File System Backend](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_file_system_backend), or I can point Config Server into manually cloned local (i.e., `file:///`) repository. But I wonder if there is such a functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off the health indicator on config server, via `spring.cloud.config.server.health.enabled=false` and `health.config.enabled=false` on the config client. Requests to config server always clone, so you need to turn down or disable health checks.

Comment: Spencergibb, Correct me if I'm wrong, but in this case any git provider outage or issue with the connection would lead to unavailability of config server (i.e. it won't be able to provide configs for the services)